# Rails mount twice in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to mount two times in my routes.rb file. Since I added ForestLiana, the second one (Facebook Messenger) is not working.

When I try to connect with Facebook on "/listen", I get the following error:

> Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno =
>   28; curl_error = Operation timed out after 6000 milliseconds with 0
>   out of 0 bytes received; HTTP Message = Unknown Response Code

Any idea how I can solve this issue and use both?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount ForestLiana::Engine => '/forest'
  resources :cards
  resources :bot_users
  resources :core_bots
  resources :letters
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", registrations: 'registrations' }

  mount Facebook::Messenger::Server, at: 'listen'
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by its not working? What does `rake routes` output for you?

Comment: The routes appear when I do rake routes. But when I go to /listen, there is a time out error, the request is not sending any data. Without Forest it was working well.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I try to load /forest, it redirects to /listen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it works if I write the ForestAdmin line with "at":

```
mount ForestLiana::Engine, at: '/forest'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
mount Facebook::Messenger::Server, at: '/listen'
```

instead of

```
mount Facebook::Messenger::Server, at: 'listen'
```

Comment: I changed it, but I get the same problem.